# How to expand the width for one div element instead of entire page

Tags: html, css, django-templates

I have the header navigation menu which needs the width 120% to be displayed in single row otherwise the text is getting into next line

If i set the width 120% for that particular div navigation menu, The Entire page width also expanding.

I don't want to increase the Entire page width Just I need to display that navigation tab menu "pharma-menu" in a single row.

This is how i am including theat menu in Django template:

```
 <div id="pharma-menu" style="width:120%">
     {% include "pharma_center/tab2.html" %}
 </div>
```

**The expanded HTML drgged from firebug:**

```
  <div style="width:120%;float:left;white-space:nowrap;" id="pharma-menu">



    <title>A very basic Superfish menu example</title>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
    <link media="screen" href="/site_media/css/superfish.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="/site_media/js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/site_media/js/hoverIntent.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/site_media/js/superfish.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // initialise plugins
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('ul.sf-menu').superfish();
    });

    </script>


    <ul class="sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-shadow">
        <li class="current">
            <a href="/pharma/search/722/" class="sf-with-ul">Patient Intelligence<span class="sf-sub-indicator"> »</span></a>
            <ul style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
                <li>
                    <a href="/pharma/search/722/">Search Keywords</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                        <a href="/pharma/patient_view/722/">Patient View Point</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                        <a href="/pharma/report/722/?category=patient">Data &amp; Research</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="/pharma/sem/722/" class="sf-with-ul">Marketing Intelligence<span class="sf-sub-indicator"> »</span></a>

            <ul style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
                <li>
                    <a href="/pharma/sem/722/">Search Engine Marketing</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="/pharma/ad/722/">Display Advertising</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="/pharma/media/722/">Social Media</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                        <a href="/pharma/report/722/?category=market">Data &amp; Research</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="">
            <a href="/pharma/sales/722/" class="sf-with-ul">Organization Intelligence<span class="sf-sub-indicator"> »</span></a>

            <ul style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
                <li>
                    <a href="/pharma/sales/722/">Sales</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="/pharma/marketing/722/">Marketing</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="/pharma/rd/722/">R&amp;D</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/pharma/clinical/722/">Clinical Trials</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                        <a href="/pharma/report/722/?category=organization">Data &amp; Research</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/pharma/comp/722/">Competitors</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/pharma/clinicalIntelligence/722/">Clinical Intelligence</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
```

**Atleast I should get the Patient Intelligence in two lines display instead of only one line display
What I have to define to display into two lines?**
[image]
If i proceed in this way The page width also getting expanded.

Comment: A working example and more code would be useful. Not much we can do with one line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
<div id="pharma-menu" style="white-space:nowrap;">
     {% include "pharma_center/tab2.html" %}
</div>
```